# How can I put the latest response from server into my arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

When my contacts are updated in my db the `response` is shown correctly but the `arraylist` is not - the `arraylist` is ok when contacts are added, but old ones that are deleted are still there when they should be gone. Can you help?

```
private void CheckifUserisContact() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(String response) {

                System.out.println("The contacts are :" + response);

                String MatchingContactsAsString = response.toString();
                System.out.println("The contacts are :" + MatchingContactsAsString);

                try {
                  JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(MatchingContactsAsString);
                  //for every object in the Array
                  for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
                    final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);

                    MatchingContactsAsArrayList.add(obj.getString("usernameMatch"));

                    //to stop duplicates sometimes happening....
                    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
                    hashSet.addAll(MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
                    MatchingContactsAsArrayList.clear();
                    MatchingContactsAsArrayList.addAll(hashSet);


                  }

          System.out.println("The contacts are :" + MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
```

First line, `System.out.println("The contacts are :" + response);`, shows:

```
[{"usernameMatch":"+123456"},{"usernameMatch":"+789012"}]
```

This is correct.

Second line, `System.out.println("The contacts are :" + MatchingContactsAsString);`, shows:`[{"usernameMatch":"+123456"},{"usernameMatch":"+789012"}]`

This is correct.

Third line, `System.out.println("The contacts are :" + MatchingContactsAsArrayList);`, shows:`[++123456, +55555, +789012]`

This is wrong. I removed, `+55555`, and yet it is still showing.

Comment: Are you sure the last printing is within the `onResponse` method otherwise it might be executed before the callback method is executed. It’s hard to see what really happens at the end since the method is incomplete

Comment: Where are you removing `+55555`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, definitely in the onResponse.

Comment: @devgianlu MatchingContactsAsArrayList.clear(); should do that.

Comment: You're not removing it, you're checking for duplicates.

Comment: Yes if 55555 is in the ArrayList it will be moved to the Set and then back to the ArrayList. Clear the list before onResponse

Comment: I used MatchingContactsAsArrayList.clear(); just before the try art and it fixed my problem.

Comment: So you did like I did in my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a response you can clear the list of its content since it will be refilled by the response values. No need to remove duplicates either.

```
private void CheckifUserisContact() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(String response) {
            //We have a response so clear the list
            MatchingContactsAsArrayList.clear();

            String MatchingContactsAsString = response.toString();

            try {
              JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(MatchingContactsAsString);
              //for every object in the Array
              for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
                final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
                final String userMatch = obj.getString("usernameMatch");
                if (!MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(userMatch) {
                    MatchingContactsAsArrayList.add(userMatch);
                }
              }

      System.out.println("The contacts are :" + MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
```

Comment: You're not checking for duplicates.

Comment: @devgianlu I removed that since the list is now being cleared first. Are you saying that you have stored duplicates and get duplicates in the response?

Comment: That's what I understood.

Comment: @devgianlu I have updated my answer and included an duplicate check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("The contacts are: " + response);

String MatchingContactsAsString = response.toString();
System.out.println("The contacts are: " + MatchingContactsAsString);

try {
 JSONArray Object = new JSONArray(MatchingContactsAsString);
 //for every object in the Array
 for (int x = 0; x < Object.length(); x++) {
  final JSONObject obj = Object.getJSONObject(x);
  MatchingContactsAsArrayList.add(obj.getString("usernameMatch"));
 }

 HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet <String> ();
 hashSet.addAll(MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
 MatchingContactsAsArrayList.clear();
 MatchingContactsAsArrayList.addAll(hashSet);

 MatchingContactsAsArrayList.remove("+55555");

 System.out.println("The contacts are: " + MatchingContactsAsArrayList);
```

Comment: I think we safely can assume there will be situations in the future when other elements will be removed and then this solution will not be very helpful

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is the only way to achieve what he is asking for. I do agree it doesn't make sense.

Comment: No it’s not the only way to do it and to hard code a value like this is really bad.